# Need to edit a line from particular section inside a file using sed in linux

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I need to edit the provider line from `[token]` section in the following file:

```
$ cat test.txt
[test]

    #provider = keystone.token.providers.uuid.Provider
    #driver = keystone.token.persistence.backends.sql.Token
    #caching = true
    #cache_time = <None>

[token]

    #provider = keystone.token.providers.uuid.Provider
    #driver = keystone.token.persistence.backends.sql.Token
    #caching = true
    #cache_time = <None>

[trust]

    #provider = keystone.token.providers.uuid.Provider
    #driver = keystone.token.persistence.backends.sql.Token
    #caching = true
    #cache_time = <None>
```

---

I tried:

```
sed -e '/^\[token\]/s/^\#provider.*/provider = keystone.token.providers.uuid.Provider/' test.txt
```

but there were no changes made to the file.

How can I change my script to edit the right section?

Comment: Is that the exact format of your data? What would you like to edit it to? Have you tried anything already? For data in blocks like this, I would personally recommend using awk instead.

Comment: ya Tom, i tried with sed but all the lines with "provider" is changing. i am ok with awk, update me

Comment: First you should update your question to show us what you've tried.

Comment: you want to uncomment token->#provider line?

Answer (score 1):

Even awk is better and clearer for understanding, however in sed

```
sed -i.bak '/\[token\]/,+2 s/#//' test.txt
```

with ,+2 you add +2 lines in range

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you could do it using awk:

```
$ awk -v RS= '/\[token]/ {f=1} f && gsub(/#provider/, "provider") {f=0}1' ORS='\n\n' file
[test]

    #provider = keystone.token.providers.uuid.Provider
    #driver = keystone.token.persistence.backends.sql.Token
    #caching = true
    #cache_time = <None>

[token]

    provider = keystone.token.providers.uuid.Provider
    #driver = keystone.token.persistence.backends.sql.Token
    #caching = true
    #cache_time = <None>

[trust]

    #provider = keystone.token.providers.uuid.Provider
    #driver = keystone.token.persistence.backends.sql.Token
    #caching = true
    #cache_time = <None>
```

Unsetting the record separator `RS` means that awk reads in each block one at a time. When `[token]` matches, the flag `f` is set. When `f` is set and the substitution is successful, `f` is unset, so no other substitutions are made. The `1` at the end is a commonly used shorthand which means that each line is printed. The `ORS` is the output record separator, which is set to two newline characters so you don't lose the space between each block.